# how to compare 3 list value with If condition

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, if-statement

Here are my lists

```
A = [32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42]
B = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
C = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
D = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Here, in list B value should be 0, in list C value should be 0 and in list D value should be 1
if this so then it is passed else failed.
As you can see in list B index 2 value is 1 so it is failed like this in list C index 1 value is 1 instead of 0 and in list D index 3,4 value is 2 instead of 1.
I've written the code for this but it is printing multiple time

I want to check the same index value for 3 list

like

```
B[0] = 0,B[1]=0
C[0] = 0,C[1]=1
D[0] = 1,D[1]=1
```

as you can see in first iteration values are correct but in 2nd time it get failed in C because 2nd index value is 1 instead of 0. like this way i want to check all 3 list.

for that reason I have taken the index from list A. you can see in my code.

my code-:

```
comment = "Wrong Signal in "
for first1 in A:
    idx_val = A.index(first1)

    if (B[idx_val] != 0):
        comment = comment + 'B' 

    if C[idx_val] != 0:
        comment = comment + 'C' 

    if D[idx_val] != 1:
        comment = comment + 'D' 
print comment

Output-'Wrong Signal in B,C,D,D,B
```

But i'm expecting the output like this

```
Output- 'Wrong Signal in B,C,D
```

and another example if B list's all value are zeros and C,D has wrong value in any index then it should print

```
output -'Wrong Signal in C,D
```

**Thank You In Advance**

Comment: Use `for b,  c,  d in zip(B, C, D)`  zip() function it allow you to iterate 2 or more lists immediately.

Comment: It isn't even necessary to iterate, you could do: `if any(B)` and `if not all(D)`

Comment: are you using python 2.7?

Comment: @kederrac yes, im using python 2.7

Comment: this will change a lot, good to know

Comment: You should add `continue` after for each `if` segment if you want to print just the first failing letter

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit your loop after you found the first instance. So you have to check if 0 is in B EVEN JUST ONCE. You can simply ask "if 0 in B". Then you can already quit, because you don't want to know how many times 0 is in B.

```
A = [32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42]
B = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
C = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
D = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]


comment = "Wrong Signal in "

def check_if_fine(List,wrong_numbers,List_name):
    No_repetitions = set(List)

    for number in wrong_numbers:
        if number not in No_repetitions:
            return ''
        else:
            return List_name

comment += check_if_fine(B,[1],'B')
comment += check_if_fine(C,[1],'C')
comment += check_if_fine(D,[2],'D')       

print(comment)
```

Comment: if `0` is in B should be fine, same for C and D

Answer (score 0):

```py
for a, b, c, d in zip(A, B, C, D):
    r = [
        key for key, value, check in zip('bcd', (b, c, d), (0, 0, 1))
        if value != check
    ]
    if r:
        print(f"{a}: wrong signal for {', '.join(r)}")
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i want. i want to iterate 3 list and want to check the same index value.

Comment: That couldn't be less clear from your original comment & I don't see what difference it actualy makes but I replaced the code for one which prints the "wrong signal" channels for every a for which there are wrong signals on channels.

Answer (score 0):

you can cast your lists to set and compare against one value:

```
def get_bad_list(lists, expected_values):
    bad_lists = ''
    for l, (s, v) in zip(lists, expected_values):
        if set(l) != v:
            bad_lists += s

    return bad_lists

bad_lists = get_bad_list([B, C, D], [('B', {0}), ('C', {0}), ('D', {1})])

if bad_lists:
    print 'Wrong Signal in ' + ', '.join(bad_lists) + '!'
else:
    print 'All good!'
```

**output:**

```
Wrong Signal in B, C, D!
```

if you want to iterate over the lists and "to check the same index value" you can use:

```
comment = "Wrong Signal in "

is_B_good = True
is_C_good = True
is_D_good = True

for index in range(len(A)):
    if is_B_good and B[index] != 0:
        is_B_good = False
        comment = comment + 'B '

    if is_C_good and C[index] != 0:
        is_C_good = False
        comment = comment + 'C '

    if is_D_good and D[index] != 1:
        is_D_good = False
        comment = comment + 'D '

print comment
```

**output:**

```
Wrong Signal in D C B
```